# Hide/unhide rows in an array based on if an entire is blank or zero in the array

Tags: excel, vba

I think I found what I need but I do not know what I am missing. I'm getting Runtime code 91 and cant find the object that needs to be defined.

```
Sub Hide_UnhideBlanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim primaryarray As Range
Dim crit1 As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Experience Rating Sheet")
Set primaryarray = ws.Range("B10:M137")
Set crit1 = ws.Range("B10:B137,M10:M137")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' unhide all rows before we begin
primaryarray.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each cell In primaryarray
    If crit1 Is Nothing Or 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The purpose of this is if `crit1` has either 0 or "" to hide all of the rows within `primaryarray` that have met the criteria described for `crit1`

Essentially my goal is for the macro to automatically hide the entire row if the array's row is completely empty using `crit1` as determining if the row is empty.

Comment: Yes i under stand that but the value has the possibility of being zero as well and there is a formula that hides zeros from a named range converting them to "". so i was just covering my bases.

what part of my logic is not understandable?

Comment: I'm not following either - seems like you're using Find() to locate values you're sourcing from the range used in the Find()?  Maybe you don't need Find() at all here?  A couple of example rows would be useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams I see your point I will fix the code to see what happens. how do i paste from excel into here?

Comment: You can take a screenshot, upload it somewhere and post the link.  Someone will add it to your post.

Comment: ok so the macro runs but the rows arent being hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm clear what you want but this might be a starting point:

```
Sub Hide_UnhideBlanks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim primaryarray As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Experience Rating Sheet")
    Set primaryarray = ws.Range("B10:M137")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' unhide all rows before we begin
    primaryarray.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each rw In primaryarray.Rows
        'not sure if you want Or/And here?
        rw.EntireRow.Hidden = ( BlankOrZero(rw.Cells(1)) Or _
                                BlankOrZero(rw.Cells(12)) )
    Next rw

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'is cell empty or zero?
Function BlankOrZero(c As Range)
    BlankOrZero = len(c.value)=0 or c.value=0
End function
```

Comment: This is a starting point thanks.  I changed it to `and` and it worked a little better.  It hid Row 137 which has text in it.

Comment: Just needed to change which columns the `rw.Cells()` checked thanks for the help.